# Reset the fragment backstack when switching tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Now im into my first question, after not finding an answer in the internet. Usually this should be a really easy thing, but it took me hours and hours so please excuse me if its a beginner question. Also i want to make sure im going the right way before spending more days just to see that in the end it just not works as i want, the way i implement it atm.

**The problem:**

My App has 3 Tabs with 3 fragments as content, one for every tab. I use Tabs because all users i asked want Tabs and not a Navigation Drawer and i listen to users, not to google (sorry). Also the 3 tabs have very different "roles" (Language Guide, Currency convertor, and own Notebook for own phrases etc) and it makes sense to split it this way (imo). If someone has other ideas, go ahead, im open :-)

The tab-navigation works as intended so far. But now i want to build the further navigation for the single Tabs an im not sure anymore wich way to go... Theres just so many way for a simple thing like this...

The first Tab has some imageButtons to further navigate into this section (See Screenshot 1), to choose a category in the language section. Of course this means the tabs should be stay in place to be able to easy switch to the Converter i.E, just the fragment from tab 1 should get switched to the new fragment (see Screenshot 2), and so on. The Buttons that you see in the below screenshot have clicklisteners that change current fragment to the new one (like "Daily")

For this i open another fragment and add it to the backstack. Maybe you already can guess what happens now. If i press the backbutton, i come back to the first fragment of course. Problems start when i switch tabs when im inside a fragment opened on tab 1. The added fragment is still in backstack what means if i press back button on Tab 2 or 3, the displayed content gets mixes up somehow with the other fragment ones. See Screenshot 3

Do i make an error somehere or can i simply tell the backstack to "reset" when switching tabs so this problem doesnt occur?

Thank you for info and sorry for language and spelling errors, english isnt my main language.

Tablistener Class to switch the tab fragments:

```
public  class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
Fragment fragment;

public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // nothing done here
}
```

}

The Fragments class from first fragment look like this (not full code):

```
public static class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, container, false);

        ImageButton catBtn_Daily = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.catBtn_Daily);
        ImageButton catBtn_OnTheRoad = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.catBtn_OnTheRoad);
        ImageButton catBtn_Shopping = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.catBtn_Shopping);
        ImageButton catBtn_Restaurant = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.catBtn_Restaurant);
        ImageButton catBtn_Romance = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.catBtn_Romance);
        ImageButton catBtn_Emergency = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.catBtn_Emergency);


        // attach an OnClickListener
        catBtn_Daily.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 // Create new fragment and transaction
                 Fragment newFragment = new FragmentTab4();

                 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                 transaction.setTransition(4097);
                 transaction.commit();
             }
        });
```

Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2, tab3;
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_test);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Home");
    tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Calculator");
    tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Notebook");

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));
    tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab3));

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
```

Cannot post pics yet, rep too low....

Please see here (third pic is called Untitled-3.png)

Screen 1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3av3pf6a17p2w42/Untitled-1.png

Screen 2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3av3pf6a17p2w42/Untitled-2.png

Screen 3: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3av3pf6a17p2w42/Untitled-3.png

Comment: This is related i think. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804704/android-fragmenttabhost-navigating-fragment-overlapping-issues-with-tabs?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

you might be better off not using the fragment back stack at all. you can maintain your own stack and override `onBackPressed()` to provide the appropriate behavior.

```
@Override protected void onBackPressed()
{
    if(myStack.isEmpty())
        super.onBackPressed(); // default handling finishes the activity
    else
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myStack.pop());
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        transaction.commit();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you, thats something to take into account, yes. But is there maybe also a function to simply re-initialize the original state when pressing another tab, or when the current tab looses focus? I cannot find this in API guide.

If not i gladly try your tip.

The navigation wont be firther into a "stack" as 2, i mean from Language-Guide fragment it goes to a category and then there will be a listview that opens a detail of an entry. Further inside will never happen.

Comment: my experience is that the builtin behavior is not as flexible as we might like. i frequently end up handling it like this, with my own stack.

Comment: Thanks again, ill try tomorrow and come back here to either accept answer or continue the advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
public void onTabSelected(YourTab tab) {
    Fragment fragment = new YourTabFragment();
    replaceRootFragment(fragment);
}

public void replaceRootFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        int id = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId();
        try {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(id, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Call onTabSelected when you click on the tab.

Comment: Hmm, where you intend to implement this? On the onTabSelected, onTabUnselected or in my button-onclick function that opens the new fragment?

Comment: Ok, it looks more promising now. Before i went into mayn problems when trying this. Ill try and update later, thank you for now.

Comment: Not sure why i neither have access to getSupportFragmentManager nor getFragmentManager, even Fragmentmanager is imported. 
Still i get cannotReloveMethod getFragmentManager()

Where does it hide? I dont get any imports with Alt*enter.

Comment: forget my last comment :-) was in wrong class. Cannot get the method because it extended Activity instead of Fragment.

Comment: Ok, probably i give up...Sure, i lack Java skills but this is just hilarious. Probably right code but i cannot set it up in my project. Basically doesnt matter what i do, i run into problems. I have to learn more about static/ non static context...With the current setup i run into this problem left & right, doesnt matter how i layout the classes. I would love this works or not but probalbly cannot tell for now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it sounds like you might want to consider a completely different approach. If I am understanding correctly you might want to consider using a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter (see the google documentation code sample here: [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)).

Essentially the viewpager presents the fragments under your tabs, the adapter provides the list of fragments to show and you select the current "page" by calling setCurrentItem on the viewpager (when the user clicks a tab). Additionally users will be able to swipe between pages (you would update the selected tab by listening to the pager events see google documentation code sample here: [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)).

This approach avoids the whole backstack issue and sounds more like what you are after.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It really makes me crazy... why even on googles Devpage have to be 5 different ways for a single problem and then why in all names NONE OF THE CODE they show in API guides fit the one you get if building a new project from (a google-)template.

Yeah, indeed this is what ive been looking before i did it the way i do it now. This is by far the better approach. Sadly i didnt see that code-example, instead i used the provided Template with a Tab & Swipepager, what is basically the same.... But the template code is far beyond my understandings.

Comment: I dont even know where i have to start when i want to add my own fragments with that example.

Why it has to be overcomplicated, all i want is a standard naviagtion? 

But ill try that example from you now, it seems more understanable. Thanks

Comment: Yah. Unfortunately that's what's known as a "Double-edged sword", the Android platform gives you a lot of freedom to express the solution to a problem in different ways.. but it is often very hard to find the best way.. and even the "best practices" are frequently changing...

Comment: Took a quick look at the ViewPager demo code.. to get your fragments into that example, call mTabsAdapter.addTab for each of your fragments in the activity onCreate.. E.G.         mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Home"),
                FragmentTab1.class, null); ..Oh, and the adapter actually creates instances of the fragments for you..